# How to store values retrieved from a loop in different variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, iteration

Just a quick question.
Suppose, I have a simple for-loop like

```
for i in range(1,11):
    x = raw_input()
```

and I want to store all the values of *x* that I will be getting throughout the loop in *different variables* such that I can use all these *different variables* later on when the loop is over.

Comment: Why are all of the valid answers here getting downvotes?

Comment: Even I can't understand that. I'm not doing it.

Comment: Looks like the downvotes seem to have now been removed, meh, I'm not complaining.

Comment: Every downvotes are removed, except the one in my answer. Can't just figure out what have I done wrong. Poor funny downvoter, didn't have time to explain the reason :D

Comment: is raw_input() function you've created?

Answer (score 14):

Create a list before the loop and store x in the list as you iterate:

```
l=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    x = raw_input()
    l.append(x)
print(l)
```

Comment: It worked in my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572659/opening-muli-tiff-files-in-a-directory-and-applying-all-same-steps/71584517#71584517 Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can store each input in a list, then access them later when you want.

```
inputs = []
for i in range(1,11);
    x = raw_input()
    inputs.append(x)


# print all inputs
for inp in inputs:
    print(inp)

# Access a specific input
print(inp[0])
print(inp[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can form a list with them.

```
your_list = [raw_input() for _ in range(1, 11)]
```

To print the list, do:

```
print your_list
```

To iterate through the list, do:

```
for i in your_list:
    #do_something
```

Comment: Even I don't get why such helpful responses are getting a down vote.

Answer (score -1):

using Python 3:

```
m=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    m.append(i**2) #your expression
print(m)

#or
m=[i**2 for i in range(1,11)]
print(m)
```