# Python 3+: How to return for loop output value to function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to assign value to function of below code:

```
def adds(y):
        for i in y:
                z = i + 1
                print(z)

x = [1, 2, 3]
adds(x)
```

output:

2

3

4

But when i tried to assigned the result to function with creating instance such:

```
# print(z) commented
p = adds(x) 
print(p)
```

output:

None

expected output:

2

3

4

gives the return inside for loop gives output: 2

gives the return inside function block or set variable z to global inside the for loop block, and recall it in the outside gives same output:  4

How do to achieve the expected output: 2 3 4, from the return value to function of above code

Comment: Please read a Python introduction. We cannot provide the tutoring that would be required to clear up all the misconceptions in this post. But for starters, your  function does not `return` anything, that's why you get `None`.

Answer (score 0):

As the **function is printing the result**, so no need to store the function value **add(z)** in variable so can return the value in function by using **(return z)** in function, Then you can store in a variable and print it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39366192/18980456

```
def adds(y):
        z = [i + 1 for i in y]
        return z

x = [1, 2, 3]
p = adds(x)
print(p)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).